# Mouse stuck after sleep/suspend

Tags: mouse, suspend, input-devices, xinput

After the computer goes to sleep or is suspended, the mouse focus is 'stuck' on whatever it was focused on last.  Basically, that means you can't click on anything else; for example, if I was using Firefox, I won't be able to click anything on the Launcher or the Menu bar (or any other application, for that matter).
I found a workaround for this bug via running

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse
```

but there ought to be a proper way of solving this issue.

Comment: Please try whether `sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all` solves your issue.

Comment: If not, determine the ID of your mouse using `xinput` and try whether `xinput --disable ID && xinput --enable ID` works.

Comment: Did you try other drivers, that may solve the problem without any cobbled together scripts.

Comment: @dessert Reinstalling didn't change anything, though I found that I was missing one of the dependencies.  I installed it and reinstalled, and it had no effect.  I called an `xinput list` and noticed I have two "PS/2 Generic Mouse" in addition to the rest of my devices (in addition to two copies of my USB receiver for cordless mouse, and a "Virtual core X test pointer".)
I disabled one of the two PS/2 Generic Mice, and the problem instantly resolved without even needing the mouse to be reset.  I've added a command to disable that input on startup, and now the issue is resolved.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be resolved by isolating the specific input device with `xinput`.  Disabling one of the two identical *PS/2 Generic Mouse* devices resolved the whole issue.

In short I entered `xinput list`, decided on one of the devices (`id=18` in my case) and then typed `xinput disable 18`. That resolved the issue, so I created an item in the *Startup Programs* list with that code, so that it runs on boot. The issue has not returned since.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could move to a **USB** mouse.  Your issue appears specific to the PS/2 port.  It's odd then, it does not affect your keyboard also.